# Make Y-axis start at 1 instead of 0 within ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some survey data where people answered how much they strongly agree, agree, disagree, strongly disagree with different statements.  Their responses could be any value (decimals included) between 1 and 4 (1 = strongly disagree, 2=disagree, etc...).

I want summarize this data by plotting the mean for each variable within a bar chart. I also want to change the Y axis labels to not be numeric values, but the labels at the anchor points of 1 = strongly disagree, 2 = disagree, etc...

Given the data included below, I can accomplish this with the following code:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=factor(key), y=value, fill=key)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", width = 0.5) +
  stat_summary(aes(label=round(..y..,1)), fun.y="mean", geom="text", vjust = -0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype="solid", color = "red", size=1.5, alpha=0.25) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"))
```

[image: chart]

This is close to what I need, but I would really like to make the Y-axis start at 1 = Strongly Disagree instead of 0.

I was thinking that I could just subtract 1 from all of the numeric responses, but then my average score labels for each bar would be incorrect.

The only constraint that I have is that I would like to accomplish this task within `ggplot`, and hopefully not by reshaping the original data.  I have another chart like this where I used `facet_wrap()` to create the same chart for each group (variable not included) within my dataset.

I've done much searching, but it seems changing the starting point of the axis in `ggplot` is not something that is typically advised.  However, given this situation, it think it sounds acceptable.

---

```
data <- structure(list(key = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Clarity", "Appropriateness", "Commitment"
), class = "factor"), value = c(NA, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
4, 4, 3, 4, NA, 3, NA, 3, 4, NA, NaN, 3, 2.66666666666667, 3, 
NA, 3.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 4, 
NA, 3, 4, 3.66666666666667, 3, 2.66666666666667, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
3, NaN, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2.33333333333333, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
3, 3, 3.33333333333333, 3, 4, 3, NA, 2.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
4, 2.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 4, 4, 3, NA, 3, 4, 3.2, 
4, 3, 4, NA, 3.2, NA, 3, 4, NA, 4, 3, 3.4, 3, NA, 2.8, 3.6, 3.6, 
3.8, NA, 3, 3.4, 3.2, 3, 3, 3.4, 3.8, 3.6, 3, 3, NaN, 2.4, 4, 
3, 3.2, 3.2, 4, 4, 2.6, 3.8, 4, 4, 3.6, 3.2, 3, 3, 4, 2.8, 4, 
3, NA, 3.4, 3.4, 4, 2.6, 3.8, 4, 3.4, 3, NA, 2.33333333333333, 
4, 3.66666666666667, 4, 3, 4, NA, 3.33333333333333, NA, 4, 4, 
NA, 4, 4, 2.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, NA, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
NA, 3.33333333333333, 3, 4, 3.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 
3.33333333333333, 4, 4, 2.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, NaN, 
3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3.66666666666667, 4, 3.33333333333333, 4, 3.66666666666667, 
4, 4, 4, 3.66666666666667, 3, 3.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 
3.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, NA, 2.33333333333333, 3, 
4, 3, 3.66666666666667, 4, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-186L))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`coord_cartesian()` gets the job done by plotting on the limited area while still retaining the data:

[image: 1]

If you use the `limits =` call in `scale_y_continuous()` your plot would break.

#### Code

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = key, y = value, fill = key)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar", width = 0.5) +
    stat_summary(aes(label = round(..y.., 1)), 
                 fun.y="mean", geom="text", vjust = -0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = "solid", 
               color = "red", size = 1.5, alpha = 0.25) +
    # limit the vertical space to 1 to 4, but keep the data
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 4)) +
                       # set ticks at 1, 2, 3, 4
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:4),
                       # label them with names
                       labels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree",
                                  "Agree", "Strongly Agree"))
```